# MapReduce using hadoop streaming via python - Pass a list from mapper to reducer and Read it as a list

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I want to pass list as the value from mapper into the reducer stage.Currently, the reducer reads the list as a string. Is there a way I can make sure that python can interpret it as a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop streaming uses `stdin` and `stdout` for its communication; therefore, everything coming into each subsequent job will be a string. You can use some kind of delimiter in your representation such as a comma:

```
the, items, in, my, list
```

and then split them in your reducer:

```py
for line in sys.stdin:
    data = line.split(',')
```

and if you want it to be a dictionary:

```py
import ast

for line in sys.stdin:
    dict = ast.literal_eval("{'waffle': 'delicious', 'pancake': 'mediocre'}")
```

There is no way to already know that it is a list though because you are reading the standard input stream.

Comment: My bad..it was a typo..it should be list rather than dictionary... ast can convert the string to dictionary, a tuple or a list. So a "list" is passed to the input parameter it will convert the string to the list.

Comment: @Swapnil: splitting the string also does this and does it out of the box without extra modules. Is there a reason to use `ast` if all you want are lists?

Comment: Yes.. The list I have is very large and each individual record in the list may contain delimiters like '\t',  ',' and others. so it will mess up with the records I fetch using split() method. AST evaluates it by using syntax grammar and gives the result i need

Answer (score 1):

Use ast.literal_eval('str_val') in reducer and will convert the string to list. For more information you can refer to https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html

Comment: Your question asks how it can be a list. You might want to modify your question if you are really looking for it to be a dictionary.